# plaintext in php simple html parse dom with "a" and "img" tag

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have simple rich text like:

```
<div><p> some text <br/> some text <br/> 
    <img src=pic.jpeg> and  <a href="web.html">link</a> </p>
</div>
```

Is it possible that I get plaintext in this case with simple html dom:

```
   some text some text <img src=pic.jpeg> and <a href="web.html">link</a>
```

I mean every tag will be remove except a tag and img tag

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ study this site. Hope you will get your answer by yourself.

Comment: In its Doc I think it is imposible! but mybe by a trick I could solve it

Comment: first try. If you fail then response here. i will solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the problem, you can do that with just [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags):

```
$str = '<div><p> some text <br/> some text <br/> 
          <img src=pic.jpeg> and  <a href="web.html">link</a> </p>
        </div>';

echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str, '<a><img>'));

// result
some text some text <img src=pic.jpeg> and <a href="web.html">link</a>
```

See [an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sqQNAV).

Note that I have only used `htmlspecialchars` to display the result in the browser.